# pdf file doesn't open

Tags: android

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://officeofthemufti.sg/MaulidBooklet.pdf");
```

I am using WebView try to loading pdf file, but all I got is empty blank. What is the problem here or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not have a PDF viewer, and WebView cannot render PDFs.

you can use the following:

```
String pdf = "http://officeofthemufti.sg/MaulidBooklet.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Answer (score 1):

The webView cannot render pdfs, you need to either launch the pdf in a new intent or use google docs to load the pdf in, ex:

`https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://link.to.your/pdf_file.pdf`